# ESLint errors/warnings should prevent compiling in React (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a **react** project initialized with **create-react-app**. I integrated Airbnb Eslint rules for my project and everything works fine! But there is one more thing that I want to do: When I break a Eslint rule I want not only to show my errors/warnings in PROBLEMS tab (VSCode) but also prevent *react-scripts* to compile my code and display them in the terminal.

PS. I don't want to eject my project and modify webpack config but I am open to use *react-app-rewired* library.

So, what do you think guys, there is any workaround for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could chain your linter and your compiler:

```
eslint "./src/**" && <<your_compiler>>
```

If you're using `npm` that can be made under scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"test": ...
"build": "eslint ./src/** && <<your_compiler>>",
...
}
```

and then execute `npm run build` (or `npm build` depending on your version)